# Is there a Prettier setting that prevents the automatic wrapping of React components in brackets when using the &&, || or ternary operator?

Tags: reactjs, prettier

When I save my component file, prettier automatically formats the return statement to this:

```
return edit ? (
  <DetailsEdit study={study} setEdit={setEdit} />
) : (
  <DetailsView study={study} setEdit={setEdit} />
);
```

Is there any way I can make it such that it formats it to this instead?

```
return edit 
    ? <DetailsEdit study={study} setEdit={setEdit} />
    : <DetailsView study={study} setEdit={setEdit} />;
```

These are the contents of my .prettierrc file

```
{
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "printWidth": 100
}
```

Comment: The problem with Prettier is the fact that it enforces blindly some guidelines but it does not actually care about readability. In my opinion it's a nice tool if you have a codebase without proper formatting and you want to reformat it quickly. However, automatic formatters are not the best tool for normal development - especially such simple ones as Prettier, which doesn't really have any options.

Comment: Prettier's formatting - including ternaries with JSX - was modeled after established community practices. Basically, that's how people who make React format their JSX. See https://prettier.io/docs/en/rationale.html#jsx

Comment: It's pretty hard to see how the prettier format is easier to read that the OP preference. I came here with the same issue, prettier makes ternary operators uglier.

Comment: @james2m The same here.

Answer (score 5):

No, there isn't. Prettier's philosophy is [to not have very many options](https://prettier.io/docs/en/option-philosophy.html), and the ones it does have are documented [here](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html).

IMO, the parenthesization is easier to read anyway, especially once the component in the ternary inevitably gets longer.

Answer (score 1):

Since it supports es5 due to its prettier structure, there is not much to do about it.

Using [Trailing Commas](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#trailing-commas)